# Transform a sync method to async with C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I have two methods. I want to wait the first one and some times wait the other (but not all the time). So I think I should use a task and await it when I want to wait, and not await it when I don't want to wait.

EDIT : in fact, I only need a fire and forget call ? :

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        JobRunner runner = new JobRunner();
        bool iWantToWait = id == 1;

        string jobId = runner.Run(!iWantToWait);
        sw.Stop();
        return Ok("Ok " + jobId + " # " + sw.Elapsed );
    }
}

public class JobRunner
{
    public string Run(bool fireAndForget)
    {
        ShortMethodIAlwaysWantToWait();
        string jobId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
        if (fireAndForget)
            HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(token => LongMethodICouldWantToWaitOrNot(jobId));
        else
            LongMethodICouldWantToWaitOrNot(jobId);
        return jobId;
    }

    private void ShortMethodIAlwaysWantToWait()
    {
        // ...
    }

    private void LongMethodICouldWantToWaitOrNot(string jobId)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class JobRunner
{
    public async Task<string> Run(bool fireAndForget)
    {
        await ShortMethodIAlwaysWantToWait();
        string jobId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
        if (fireAndForget)
            HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem((token) => LongMethodICouldWantToWaitOrNot(jobId));
        else
            await LongMethodICouldWantToWaitOrNot(jobId);
        return jobId;
    }

    private async Task LongMethodICouldWantToWaitOrNot(string jobId)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
    }

    private async Task ShortMethodIAlwaysWantToWait()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
    }
}
```

Take care of background Task on AspNet, before .Net 4.5.2, you shouldn't "fire and forget" an async method, since the Thread can be aborted before the end of the Task. Since 4.5.2 you can use [HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn636892%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: You're not awaiting `ShortMethodIAlwaysWantToWait`

Comment: although note that this changes the behaviour slightly since LongMethod is now run on the same thread. Easily modifiable to run on another thread with `await Task.Run()` though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Thread.Sleep is of course an example, I'm accessing some ressources. Do I need to have an async LongMethodICouldWantToWaitOrNot ? Or can it only be a void ?

Comment: Usually, all methods taking longer than 40 or 50 ms should be transformed as a Task. If resources are on network or on disk, the answer is directly yes.

Comment: @Sharped `await LongMethodICouldWantToWaitOrNot` will always asynchronously wait on that method. Is that what the OP really wants?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I neither understand the question not these answers. This is XYProblem for sure.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I added the option. Good idea

Comment: `ConfigureAwait(false)` for task which you're not awaiting makes no sense. Correct me if I'm wrong. Also if `LongMethodICouldWantToWaitOrNot` is asynchronous you don't need `Task.Run`. If not asynchronous why does even it returns a `Task` ?

Comment: @Sharped Using `Task.Run` in ASP.NET is dangerous. You shouldn't do that.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov good idea again, I miss it was run from an `ApiController`

Comment: I'm using web api and prior to 4.5.2. Should I use Thread instead of task ?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't. Read this articles : http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx and http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html

Comment: In fact, it's a problem only when the pool is recycled ?

Comment: Yes, but there is a lot of reasons for a pool to be recycled, you should better consider upgrading your solution to 4.5.2

Comment: ok, in fact I don't need any async/await for my purpose ... the only thing is to fire and forget when needed, with QueueBackgroundWorkItem, or call normal method

Answer (score 0):

```
        public async Task<string> Run()
        {
            ShortMethodIAlwaysWantToWait();
            string jobId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");

            if (iwantToAWait) {
                var task = Task.Run(() => LongMethodICouldWantToWaitOrNot(jobId));
                await task;
            }
            else
               LongMethodICouldWantToWaitOrNot(jobId)

            return jobId;
        }
```

This way the `Task` is either awaited: the control is returned to the caller, who then can decide whether to wait or await, or the `Task` is waited for while blocking the current thread.

You may want to either change your action to be `async` and update the call to:

```
string jobId = await runner.Run();
```

Or you can do the same using `Task<string>`

```
var task = runner.Run();
task.Wait();
string jobId = task.Result;
```

Edit: it is important whether the LongMethodICouldWantToWaitOrNot is doing CPU bound operation, in which case it make sense to run it with `Task.Run`, or whether the 'slowness' of the method is caused by I/O operations in which case you should make it `async` and I cannot see any reason for running it synchronously

Comment: `Wait` inside `async` method? and What's the point in executing in threadpool thread and waiting for it synchronously? Why not just call `LongMethodICouldWantToWaitOrNot`?

Comment: That's what OP asked for. I not a proponent of challenging the questions. He wants to Wait or await depending on something... executing in threadpool is indeed unnecessary.. updating the answer.

Comment: I read the question as sometimes await and sometimes not. I can't see where OP asked to wait synchronously. Really question is unclear atleast for me. But, if you want to wait synchronously inside `async` method, you're doing something terribly wrong.

Comment: In this very specific case the await allows to return the control to the caller. The caller can then run other things, which will be in parallel to LongMethodICouldWantToWaitOrNot. @Sriram "But, if you want to wait synchronously inside async method, you're doing something terribly wrong" would you care to explain? Opinionated statements without factual explanation are the best tool in any discourse! ;-)